# Data loss in codeigniter post

Tags: php, codeigniter, post

I am doing this in test.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST)) print_r($_POST);
?>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="questions[Global Questions][question 1]" placeholder="Your answer">
<input type="text" name="questions[Global Questions][question 2]" placeholder="Your answer">
<input type="submit" value="Submit answers"/>
</form>
```

It is printing the data as:

```
Array
(
    [questions] => Array
        (
            [Global Questions] => Array
                (
                    [question 1] => one
                    [question 2] => two
                )
        )
)
```

but when I try to do the exact html code in codeigniter view and `if(isset($_POST)) print_r($_POST);` in controller. It is giving this output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => two
        )
)
```

Also, when I post the codeigniter form to `test.php`, `test.php` prints it well. Only the codeigniter is manipulating the value received.

Comment: what version of CI do you use?

Comment: codeigniter version: 3.1.0

Comment: have you tried accessing it via the $this->input->post()

Comment: Yes. I actually got the same result. -- the wrong one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<input type="text" name="questions[Global_Questions][question_2]" placeholder="Your answer">
```

if you insist

Create a file named application/core/MY_Input.php, and declare your class with:

```
class MY_Input extends CI_Input {
    public function __construct()
{

    $this->_allow_get_array = (config_item('allow_get_array') === TRUE);
    $this->_enable_xss = (config_item('global_xss_filtering') === TRUE);
    $this->_enable_csrf = (config_item('csrf_protection') === TRUE);
    $this->_standardize_newlines = (bool)config_item('standardize_newlines');

    $this->security =& load_class('Security', 'core');

    // Do we need the UTF-8 class?
    if (UTF8_ENABLED === TRUE) {
        $this->uni =& load_class('Utf8', 'core');
    }

    // Sanitize global arrays
    // $this->_sanitize_globals(); // i commented this line

    log_message('info', 'Input Class Initialized');

}
}
```

That will override the Input class construct, hence your desired result

Hope it helps

Comment: Actually, that doesn't matter - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16182178/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-use-spaces-in-php-associative-array-indexes -- Plus, why is it working in core php and just not working with the codeigniter then?

Comment: However, let me try getting rid of the spaces

Comment: Interestingly that worked. But I need the spaces in those array keys. How do I handle this? with quotation? Let's try that

Comment: how about you do a str_replace() inside your controller

Comment: Yes. I mean, I can replace spaces with underscore and again later replace underscore with spaces. But, that is not neat way to do that. I think there's some other way too

Comment: The biggest question here is, why did that worked with core code but not with codeigniter

Comment: the CodeIgniter Input class library sanitises globals before it reaches the controller

Comment: How do I prevent that?

Comment: Extend the library, and overwrite the existing controller omitting this line
        $this->_sanitize_globals();

Comment: you should check CI documentation on how to extend a library here https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html

Comment: Can you please post an answer for this?